# Direct3D9 Calculating view space point light position

Tags: view, directx, rendering, space, light

I am working on my own deffered rendering engine. I am rendering the scene to the g-buffer containing diffuse color, view space normals and depth (for now). I have implemented directional light for the second rendering stage and it works great. Now I want to render a point light, which is a bit harder.

I need the point light position for the shader in view space because I have only depth in the g-buffer and I can't afford a matrix multiplication in every pixel. I took the light position and transformed it by the same matrix, by which I transform every vertex in shader, so it should align with verices in the scene (using D3DXVec3Transform). But that isn't the case: transformed position doesn't represent viewspace position nearly at all. It's x,y coordinates are off the charts, they are often way out of the (-1,1) range. The transformed position respects the camera orientation somewhat, but the light moves too quick and the y-axis is inverted. Only if the camera is at (0,0,0), the light stands at (0,0) in the center of the screen. Here is my relevant rendering code executed every frame:

```
D3DXMATRIX matView;    // the view transform matrix
D3DXMATRIX matProjection;    // the projection transform matrix

D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
                   &D3DXVECTOR3 (x,y,z),    // the camera position
                   &D3DXVECTOR3 (xt,yt,zt),    // the look-at position
                   &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));    // the up direction

D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                           fov,    // the horizontal field of view
                           asp,    // aspect ratio
                           znear,    // the near view-plane
                           zfar);    // the far view-plane

D3DXMATRIX vysl=matView*matProjection;

eff->SetMatrix("worldViewProj",&vysl); //vertices are transformed ok ín shader

//render g-buffer

D3DXVECTOR4 lpos; D3DXVECTOR3 lpos2(0,0,0);

D3DXVec3Transform(&lpos,&lpos2,&vysl); //transforming lpos into lpos2 using vysl, still the same matrix
eff->SetVector("poslight",&lpos); //but there is already a mess in lpos at this time

//render the fullscreen quad with wrong lighting
```

Not that relevant shader code, but still, I see the light position this way (passing IN.texture is just me being lazy):

```
float dist=length(float2(IN.texture0*2-1)-float2(poslight.xy));
OUT.col=tex2D(Sdiff,IN.texture0)/dist;
```

I have tried to transform a light only by matView without projection, but the problem is still the same. If I transform the light in a shader, it's the same result, so the problem is the matrix itself. But it is the same matrix as is transforming the vertices! How differently are vertices treated?

Can you please take a look at the code and tell me where the mistake is? It seems to me it should work ok, but it doesn't. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a matrix multiplication to reconstruct view position, here is a code snippet (from andrew lauritzen deffered light example)

tP is the projection transform, position screen is -1/1 pixel coordinate and viewspaceZ is linear depth that you sample from your texture.

```
float3 ViewPosFromDepth(float2 positionScreen,
                            float viewSpaceZ)
{
    float2 screenSpaceRay = float2(positionScreen.x / tP._11,
                               positionScreen.y / tP._22);

    float3 positionView;
    positionView.z = viewSpaceZ;
    positionView.xy = screenSpaceRay.xy * positionView.z;

    return positionView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with something similar myself :D But in world space. I calculate world-space position from depth map with distance from camera using formula

    pos=pEye+IN.cpos*depth

where IN.cpos is interpolated position of the screen corner  and pEye is eye position.

Comment: Nice, just wondering why using world space for light? (I used world before but found using view space much easier, specially if you start to use a bit more complex equations).

Comment: Well, I can set positions and directions to the shader directly, without any transforms. I will see how it will go... I might switch to view space in the future, now it's simpler for me to use world space. :) (there is some problem about precision, right?)

Comment: Precision is not that bad, one nice thing is you need viewer direction for specular component, which in view space is just the normalized position, so it saves you some extra work. here is a link about it http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/position-from-depth-3/

Answer (score 0):

Result of this transform `D3DXVec3Transform(&lpos,&lpos2,&vysl);` is a  vector in homogeneous space(i.e. projected vector but not divided by `w`). But in you shader you use it's `xy` components without respecting this(`w`). This is (quite probably) the problem. You could divide vector by its `w` yourself or use `D3DXVec3Project` instead of `D3DXVec3Transform`.

It's working fine for vertices as (I suppose) you `mul` them by the same `viewproj` matrix in the vertex shader and pass transformed values to interpolator where hardware eventually divides it's `xyz` by interpolated 'w'.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the root of a problem. I used D3DXVec3Project, adjusted the coordinates and it works great! Thank you, I wouldn't guessed that.